# Case insensitve path matching on nginx and linux

Tags: linux, redirect, nginx, case-insensitive

I have a website that has moved from a Windows web server to nginx on Linux.  There are templates that I can't modify that have links to files in a multi level folder structure (more than 10k files).  These files and links were created without case sensitivity.  Now that the site is on Linux I have thousands of broken links because of case.

Is there a redirect block I can add into my PHP code to handle the case insensitive redirect?

I've found lot of examples on how to do this with a specific redirect, but how do I do it for an unknown amount paths?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the bad explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a sticky problem.

The first suggestion is normalize the directory and file names.  If you can convert them all to lower case, then you could use a `try_files $uri $uri_lowercase`

The second suggestion is to create symlinks for directories and file that have case mismatches, i.e. if links refer to images and Images, but the directory is images, create a symbolic link with `ln -s images Images`

Obviously normalizing or creating symlinks would be easier/faster with a shell script.